# Parsing RSS with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to parse RSS: http://www.mlssoccer.com/rss/en.xml .

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load($url)
$items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach($items as $key => $item) 
{
    $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    $pubDate = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    $description = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    // do some stuff
}
```

The thing is: I'm getting "$title" and "$pubDate" without a problem, but for some reason "$description" is always empty, there's nothing in it. What could be the reason for such behaviour and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with CDATA you need to use textContent instead of nodeValue to retreive value beetween

```
<?php

$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load('http://www.mlssoccer.com/rss/en.xml');
$items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach($items as $key => $item) 
{
    $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    $pubDate = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    $description = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->textContent; // textContent

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :-). Although it's a bit of a mystery to me - the "title" field was also a CDATA and worked with "->firstChild->nodeValue"...

Answer (score 1):

Here can be whitespaces between the opening `<description>` tag and the opening `<![CDATA[`. This is a text node.

So if you access the firstChild of `description`, you might fetch that whitespace text node.

In a generic way you can set the DOMdocument to ignore whitespace nodes:

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->preserveWhiteSpace  = FALSE;
$feed->load($url);
```

Additionally you should check out XPath, it makes reading a DOM much easier:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($feed);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//channel/item') as $item) {
    $title = $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item);
    $pubDate = $xpath->evaluate('string(pubDate)', $item);
    $description = $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $item);
    // do some stuff
    var_dump([$title, $pubData, $description]);
}
```